# Skip 64k limitation Android while testing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, testing

Is there some workaround to skip the 64k method limitation while testing my Android app in the emulator?

Comment: Have you read the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use proguard and try to shrink your code. This would be the preferred option.

Otherwise, make it multidex (but I don't see how it'll be "just for testing" unless you still shrink your code before deploying it).

You can achieve that by one of the three easy ways:

1. If you have an application class, simply make it extend `MultidexApplication` (rather than simply `Application`).
2. If you don't have an application class, you can add the `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultidexApplication"` attribute to your application tag in `AndroidManifest.xml`
3. If you have an application class but can't override `MutlidexApplication` (because you're not overriding `Application` to begin with but some other custom application class), add the following override:

   ```
   @Override
   protected void attachBaseContext(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Multidex.install(this);
   }
   ```

[if you are supporting API levels lower than 21, you'll need to add the `android-support-multidex.jar` dependency to your project. It can be found under the `extras` folder in the android-sdk directory]

Answer (score 1):

there is no workaround beyond proguard stripping off enough to get you below the limit if you're lucky. just implement multidex. it's very easy now.

Answer (score 0):

The Limit is 64 x 1024 = 65.536 Methods. That means 64K Methods.
You can't change this maximum, but you can shrink the libraris. All you need to do is to shorten the librarys like this:

Bad:

```
compile 'com.google:9.6.1'
```

better:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
```